# Flash is dead... what do I do?

Tags: flash, unity-game-engine, canvas, 2d, adobe

Recently I felt like I wanted to create a website for 2d games. I have never developed a game and I have no idea how the thing goes. So I first researched the most popular tools today to see which one I was most interested in. I found two: flash and canvas. When I was a child I never liked Flash. The idea of having to download adobe flash just to play always brought me problems and made the browser slower. So I decided for canvas. I was watching a lot about canvas games and animation. I compared it with unity, and I found that, compared to this, canvas is still very limited. I was watching 2d games made in unity and I loved them. I searched how I could do to upload a 2d game made in unity to the web, and I found that it has to be supported by flash... but adobe killed flash. So, my questions are: is there any way to upload a 2d game made in unity to a website without requiring flash? I would have to forget about websites and focus on cell phones or steam?

Comment: "I searched how I could do to upload a 2d game made in unity to the web, and I found that it has to be supported by flash... but adobe killed flash" I don't know where you have read that, but applications made with Unity for the web target WebGL, which does not require Flash at all. Please, take some time to read the Unity manual : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using Flash use WebGL:

1. Install WebGL For Unity: [WebGL For Unity 2017.3.03f3](http://download.unity3d.com/download_unity/a9f86dcd79df/TargetSupportInstaller/UnitySetup-WebGL-Support-for-Editor-2017.3.0f3.exe)
2. Go to your project and change the target platform to WebGL.
3. Build your project.
4. Deploy it.

More info: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-deploying.html
And: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl.html